# How to make sites unavailable to user PHP?

Tags: php, html, web, include

I´m using a lot of including while coding pages to keep the code a little bit more beutiful and avoid typing code multiple times.

example of index.php:

```
<?php 
include 'header.php';
?>

<p> random HTML </p> 

<?php
    include 'foo.php';
?>
```

The 'problem' now is that clients are able to navigate to www.page.de/foo.php and see this content. Is there a PHP-way to solve this without playing on .htaccess?

Comment: *"Is there a PHP-way to solve this without playing on .htaccess?"* - There are too many ways to do this.

Comment: Do you have a user database?

Comment: One good practice solution is enough.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner yes i have a user database but why is that important?

Comment: Seeing the comments you left in an answer, I see that it appears to not fulfill what you're asking. If you're using a database as you mention, then there are many ways to do this. However, if you feel that the answer solved the question, consider accepting it.

Answer (score 3):

Don't place php files you don't want users to see in the public/ directory.

Edited out mention of .htaccess since you edited that into your question specification

Comment: It´s not that user should not see the file. he sees it anyway. things like "if logged in" is already taken into consideration, but still they can have a look at these pages... Lets say the include is the login formular: It is shown on frontpage anyway, but www.page.de/login.php shows just the formular without the rest of HTML + CSS design

Comment: Short but essentially correct; PHP **can** require/include files that are *not* within the document root but they **can't** be accessed directly over HTTP.

Comment: I believe it is done through the [`include_path`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9345109/php-ini-include-path), if I remember correctly.

Comment: so lets say I create a private folder (which is not includet into document root) and put foo.php into it and include it into my index.php file my Problem is solved?

Comment: Correct @devNull what we have in our flagship product is a public/ directory with an entrypoint file. All other php files (which we wrote) are kept in the application/ directory. Every good PHP framework does it this way or a similar way