# How can I output Math.php in PHP?

Tags: php

Warning: include(Math.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\php ModulesAndNamespaces\php modules & namespaces.php on line 13

```php
<?php
// modules-> divide and reuse codes
    //Math.php
    define( 'PI', 3.14);

    function add($a,$b) {
        echo $a+$b;
    }
?>
<?php
    //App.php
    include ('Math.php');
    echo PI;// 3.14
    echo add(1,2);//3
?>
```

Why do I get this error, and how can the problem be fixed?

Comment: `Math.php` isn't in one of the directories in  `include_path` in your `php.ini`. If you want it to search the same directory as the calling script, make sure `.` is in the include path.

Comment: Thanks. You are the first one of my stackoverflow journey.

Comment: I am newbee so what should i change that problem.Your answer will be correct but i cant understand

Comment: Edit `php.ini` and put `.:` at the beginning of the `include_path` value.

Comment: include ('php.ini.:Math.php');

Comment: Like  that ? bro..

Comment: No. I said to edit your `php.ini` file, not your script. There will be a line that looks like `include_path = "some directories"`, put `.:` at the beginning of the list of directories.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9345109/php-ini-include-path

Comment: For XAMPP, the php.ini is typically at `c:\xampp\php\php.ini` (or [installation_path]\php\php.ini )